# Tomcat Freezes just one application

Tags: mysql, tomcat, lamp

I have an Ubuntu LAMJ server running Tomcat6.

One of my JSP applications freezes every couple of days and I am having trouble figuring out why. I have to reboot tomcat to get that one app going again, as it won't cone back on its own. I am getting nothing in my own log4j logs for that app, and can't see anything in Catalina.out either.

This applications shares a javax.sql.DataSource resource with another, via a context element in the server.xml file. I don't think this is the cause of the problem, but I may as well mention it.

Could anyone point me in the right direction to find the cause of this intermittent issue?

thanks in advance,

Christy

Comment: can you take thread dumps? or is the whole process frozen?

Comment: Hi Sean. It's just one app which freezes. All other apps run file while this one is frozen. How would I take a thread dump from this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a Thread dump of the running server
There are two options

**Use VisualVM**

in your %java_home%/bin folder there will be a file called jvisualvm. Run this and connect to your tomcat server. Click the Threads tab and then "Thread Dump"

**Manually from the Command Line**

open up a command line and find the process id for your tomcat

```
ps -ef | grep java
```

Once you identify the process ID for the running tomcat instance,

```
kill -3 <pid>
```

replace the process Id here. This will send your thread dump to the stdout for your tomcat. Most likely catalina.out file.

**edit** - As per Mark's comments below:

> It is normal to take 3 thread dumps ~10s apart and compare them. It
>   makes it much easier to see which threads are 'stuck' and which ones
>   are moving

---

Once you have the thread dump you can analyse it for stuck threads. It may not be stuck threads as the problem, but at least you can see what is going on inside the server to analyze the problem further.

Comment: Thank you Sean, that's certainly a step in the right direction. How do I find the thread id for just one application? I currently have to reboot the whole of Tomcat to restart, as I don't know how to just reboot one app.

Comment: if they are all running on the same tomcat server, they share the same process id

Comment: It is normal to take 3 thread dumps ~10s apart and compare them. It makes it much easier to see which threads are 'stuck' and which ones are moving.

Comment: @Christy see Mark's recent comment. This is important, I forgot to mention it earlier

Comment: Thank you @Mark and Sean, you've both been very helpful. My Tomcat6 process appears to be 13868, so I will run "kill -3 13868" while it is frozen, 3 times, 10 seconds apart. Then restart Tomcat. Now, I am in the odd position of waiting for it to freeze! Thanks